# Cleaning up web parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm just practicing and decided I'd like to know the the #1 money maker in PGA from 1980 to 2015

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
base_url = 'http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.109.'
def get_links():
    urls = []
    for i in range(1980,2015):
        urls.append(base_url+str(i)+'.html')
    return urls
def get_first(urls):
    for url in urls:
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup =  BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        player = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'player-name'})
        print (player)

get_first(get_links())
```

So the problem I am running into two problems.

1. This returns and entire link whereas I only want the players name.
2. I only want the first player not the entire years worth.

I tried to solve problem 2 by changing the findAll to find. 
Unfortunately that only returned Player Name as that is the first entry to all the pages. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the only the first player name you should use this code:

```
player = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'player-name'})
if len(player) > 2:
    first_player_name = player[1].find('a').get_text()
```

I skip the first "player" (since that td only contains the title of the column - `Player Name`, then 
Now you can do whatever you want with the name of the first player (print, add to some list

Comment: Thanks so much. This solved my issue! just one question. What exaclty does ('a').get_text() do?

Comment: `find('a')` returns the first element of the tag 'a'. the `get_text()` function returns the text content of that tag.
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text